# Parsing xml with & < > " ' by java DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

Good day ppl.

I have class:

```
public class XmlModifier {

    private DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = null;
    private DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    private Document document = null;
    private TransformerFactory transformFactory = null;
    private Transformer transform = null;
    private DOMSource source = null;
    private StreamResult streamRes = null;
    private boolean exepDocBuilderAlarm = true;

    public XmlModifier() {
        this.docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            this.docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            this.exepDocBuilderAlarm = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void prepareXMLMessage(File file, String userName, String userPassword, String reqId, Integer NUMBER_OF_MSG_SENDS) {
        if (exepDocBuilderAlarm != false) {
            try {
                document = docBuilder.parse(file);
                setElementValues("si:sourceInfo", addElementsToArray("si:reqId,si:reqTag"), addElementsToArray(reqId + "," + reqId), NUMBER_OF_MSG_SENDS);
                setElementValues("usr:user", addElementsToArray("usr:id,usr:password"), addElementsToArray(userName + "," + userPassword), NUMBER_OF_MSG_SENDS);
                setElementValues("meth:method", addElementsToArray("meth:id,meth:tag"), addElementsToArray(reqId + "," + reqId), NUMBER_OF_MSG_SENDS);
                setElementValues("tb:tradeField", addElementsToArray("tb:value"), addElementsToArray(reqId), NUMBER_OF_MSG_SENDS);
                this.transformFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                this.transform = transformFactory.newTransformer();
                this.source = new DOMSource(document);
                this.streamRes = new StreamResult(file);
                this.transform.transform(source, streamRes);
                System.out.println("Done to execute XmlModifier");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                this.docFactory = null;
                this.docBuilder = null;
                this.transformFactory = null;
                this.transform = null;
                this.source = null;
                this.streamRes = null;
            }
        }
    } 

    private void setElementValues(String rootElement, String[] childElements, String[] childElementsValues, Integer msgIDIncrement) {
        Node nodeRootElement = document.getElementsByTagName(rootElement).item(0);
        NodeList childElementlist = nodeRootElement.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < childElementlist.getLength(); z++) {
                Node node = childElementlist.item(z);
                if (childElements[i].equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                    node.setTextContent(childElementsValues[i]);
                }
            }
        } 

    }

    private String[] addElementsToArray(String elements) {
        String[] theArray = null;
        theArray = elements.split(",");
        return theArray;
    }
}
```

On input I have xml which is not well formed sometimes. The problem of DOM parser is that in my point of view DOM parser parsing whole xml from the beggining which my have special symbols like `< > & " '` is not good for me.

How can I on input to `prepareXMLMessage(..)` provide xml with  `< > & " '`,  then in prepareXMLMessage(..) parse it with no problems(change some values inside elements) and than as output provide xml with `< > & " '` back???

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you tried to [search](https://www.google.pl/search?q=java+parse+malformed+xml&oq=java+parse+malf&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3043j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)? It's a quite common problem.